# XPath Bug in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xpath

I need to access a XML document I created with JavaScript via XPath. If I load an XML file from a server (via XMLHttpRequest) it works fine, but if I use the XML document reference from the local created XML document Chrome didn't show anything, while Firefox did what I expected.

Here a bit of example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xml = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);

        var root = xml.createElement("root");

        var level1 = xml.createElement("L1");
        var level2 = xml.createElement("L2");
        L2txt = xml.createTextNode("here is L2");

        level2.appendChild(L2txt);
        level1.appendChild(level2);

        var level2 = xml.createElement("L2");
        level2.setAttribute("id", "myId");
        L2txt = xml.createTextNode("here is L2 with id");

        level2.appendChild(L2txt);
        level1.appendChild(level2);
        root.appendChild(level1);

        path="//L2[@id='myId']";

        var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, root, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result=nodes.iterateNext();

        while (result) {
          document.write(result.textContent);
          document.write("<br />");
          result=nodes.iterateNext();
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the Code should output "here is L2 with id".

I use FF 9.0.1 and Chrome 16.0.912.75 m the development tools don't show any error or hint.

Now I don't realy know, is it a bug in Chrome or an 'extra' feature in Firefox. And - most importent - how could I bring Chrome round to act like Firefox. Or do you have another idea how to use XPath on local created XML documents?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a small problem in your example code.

The `root` element is never added to the XML document (the `xml` variable).

Therefore the XPath search cannot work since the `xml` document object has no root element and therefore no content to search. Try adding :

```
xml.appendChild(root);
```

After this:

```
var root = xml.createElement("root");
```

That fixes the issue for me in Chrome.

Comment: wow, thank you very much, I don't know why I missed this *-* .. well but Firefox also accepted the old version ... Chrome seems to be very correct ;-)